# Combine meshes in Unity at runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I'm trying to combine "seats prefabs" into a single mesh at runtime to save some draw calls.

My seat contains 2 MeshFilter, a base and a top (= the seat, red on the picture) with 2 different materials. My seat is created from an imported FBX which has read/Write enabled.

I'm using pooling if it matters : I generate 500 seats, then I pick 250 from the pool to create my stands, then I combine them, release the pooled seats and reuse them to combine another stands.

Here is the issue that appears on some seats (not all, only the 5th and 6th stands so maybe linked to some pooling issue ? reusing the same mesh several times), some "tops" of seats are "linked" together
[image]

Here is the function I use :

```
  List<CombineInstance> baseList = new List<CombineInstance>();
        List<CombineInstance> topList = new List<CombineInstance>();

        Material materialTop = null;
        Material materialBase = null;

        //Loop through the array with trees
        for (int i = 0; i < seats.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject currentSeat = seats[i];


            //Get all meshfilters from this seat, true to also find deactivated children
            MeshFilter[] meshFilters = currentSeat.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>(true);


            //Loop through all children
            for (int j = 0; j < meshFilters.Length; j++)
            {
                MeshFilter meshFilter = meshFilters[j];

                CombineInstance combine = new CombineInstance();

                //Is it top or base?
                MeshRenderer meshRender = meshFilter.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();

                string materialName = meshRender.gameObject.name;

                if (materialName.Contains("top"))
                {
                    combine.mesh = meshFilter.mesh;
                    combine.transform = meshFilter.transform.localToWorldMatrix;

                    //Add it to the list of leaf mesh data
                    topList.Add(combine);

                    if (materialTop == null) materialTop = meshRender.material;
                }
                else if (materialName.Contains("base"))
                {
                    combine.mesh = meshFilter.mesh;
                    combine.transform = meshFilter.transform.localToWorldMatrix;

                    //Add it to the list of wood mesh data
                    baseList.Add(combine);

                    if (materialBase == null) materialBase = meshRender.material;
                }
            }


            //Deactivate the seat the pool 
            GameController.This.Prefabs.DestroyPooledObject(currentSeat);
        }


        //First we need to combine the bases into one mesh and then the tops into one mesh
        Mesh combinedBaseMesh = new Mesh();
        combinedBaseMesh.CombineMeshes(baseList.ToArray());

        Mesh combinedTopMesh = new Mesh();
        combinedTopMesh.CombineMeshes(topList.ToArray());

        //Create the array that will form the combined mesh
        CombineInstance[] totalMesh = new CombineInstance[2];

        //Add the submeshes in the same order as the material is set in the combined mesh
        totalMesh[0].mesh = combinedBaseMesh;
        totalMesh[0].transform = parent.transform.localToWorldMatrix;
        totalMesh[1].mesh = combinedTopMesh;
        totalMesh[1].transform = parent.transform.localToWorldMatrix;

        //Create the final combined mesh
        Mesh combinedAllMesh = new Mesh();

        //Make sure it's set to false to get 2 separate meshes
        combinedAllMesh.CombineMeshes(totalMesh, false);

        var meshFilterParent = parent.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        if (meshFilterParent == null) meshFilterParent = parent.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        meshFilterParent.sharedMesh = combinedAllMesh;


        var meshRenderer = parent.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        if (meshRenderer == null) meshRenderer = parent.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        meshRenderer.materials = new
            Material[]
            {
                materialBase,
                materialTop
            };
```

Comment: Pass `true` instead of `false` to the second param of the `CombineMeshes(totalMesh, false);` function

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, and by doing that the second material is not applied anymore and I get the message "This renderer has more materials than the mesh has submeshes"

Comment: Little bit late, but by default, combinemesh has a vertex limit of 65536. If you go over that, it will have 'stringing' problems. I think that might be your problem